# Powershell not prompting for additional input after Out-GridView has been selected

Tags: powershell, change-password, multiple-choice, distinguishedname, out-gridview

Below the Get-ADUser, $NewPassword, Set-ADAccountPassword are not working or not even prompting after making a selection in the gridview.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$x = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter Search Query for Name"
Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -like '*$x*'" -Properties DisplayName | 
$choice = (Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -like '$x'" -Properties DisplayName | Select-Object Name, DistinguishedName | Out-GridView -PassThru)
if($choice) { # if the user selected an item from the DGV and pressed `OK`
    $choice.DistinguishedName
    Get-ADUser -Identity $choice.DistinguishedName -Properties * | Select-Object SamAccountName, Enabled, LockedOut, AccountLockoutTime, BadLogonCount | Out-Host
    $NewPassword = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter New Password for $choice.DistinguishedName"
    Set-ADAccountPassword -Server *REDACTED* -Identity "$choice.DistinguishedName" -NewPassword $NewPassword -Reset
}
else { # user clicked `Cancel` or closed the DGV
    exit
}
```

Below the same Get-ADUser, Write-Host, and Unlock-ADAccount are not working after selecting an item from the Grid-View to unlock the account.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$ous = Search-ADAccount -LockedOut -UsersOnly 
$choice = $ous | Select-Object Name, DistinguishedName | Out-GridView -PassThru
if($choice) { # if the user selected an item from the DGV and pressed `OK`
    $choice.DistinguishedName
    Get-ADUser -Identity $choice.DistinguishedName -Properties * | Select-Object SamAccountName, Enabled, LockedOut, AccountLockoutTime, BadLogonCount | Out-Host
    Write-Host "Unlocking $choice.DistinguishedName"
    Unlock-ADAccount -Server *REDACTED* -Identity $choice.DistinguishedName
}
else { # user clicked `Cancel` or closed the DGV
    exit
}
```

Comment: Where do you define the variable `$choice`?  ... and you may provide an `-OutputMode` for `Out-GridView`

Comment: Defining $choice from the piped Out-GridView -PassThru

Comment: OK, but you did not in your original / first code sample.

Comment: I dont understand your replies and what you are trying to convey.

Comment: In the first code snippet you forgot to define the variable `$Choice`, Therefore the if statement `if($choice) ` validates to `$False`.  ‍♂️

Comment: $choice = (Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -like '*$x*'" -Properties DisplayName | Select-Object Name, DistinguishedName | Out-GridView -PassThru)

Comment: Did you use that code line? Because in your first code snippet it is not there!!!! Take a look at the code in your question!

Comment: Clarify on what "not working" means... note that you're using `-Server` and AD replication does not happen instantly.

Comment: The not working portion would be the script itself. I have the *REDACTED* part correct for a server that i listed the FQDN correctly that has a 7-9 min delay from where I am located. that string is correct. The not working part was the setting the choice. Now its not unlocking or setting the password using the $choice.Distinguished name on the Set-AD-AccountPassword and Unlock-AdAccount.  @Olaf it works now. I cannot believe I missed that variable set string.

Comment: Sometimes we can't see the wood for the trees.  ‍♂️  